# IE8 unhide with css only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have

```
...
<table>
<tbody>
<tr style="display: none;" class="print_display"><td>stuff ....</td>/tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

problem is i **can't unhide it in IE8**
i have a print_css that kicks in when user tries to print and it has

```
tr.print_display
    {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: table-row !important;
        visibility: visible !important;   /* IE bug*/
    }
```

nothing works

Is it possible to unhide it with css only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tr.print_display
    {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: block !important;
    }
```

Also your markup is invalid. Replace with:

```
<tr style="display: none;" class="print_display"><td>stuff ....</td></tr>
```

I'm using `</tr>` instead of `/tr>`

http://jsfiddle.net/8jqHE/

Comment: yeah, that's a copy-paste bug, thank you it worked!!! gonna accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: display block ruins layout in firefox :(

Comment: Check this in other browsers, with a table with multiple columns and rows. I think you will have problems with "display:block" on a <tr>

Comment: @max4ever - Sorry I wasn't aware of this when answering the question. It might be worth unmarking the answer so others can answer

Comment: i ended up creating a new css file and using conditional css

Answer (score 2):

I know you said 'css only', but I don't think it will work. Can you use some javascript to do the deed? If so, set the value of style.display to "" (empty string). This works in all browsers to display a table row. Setting it to "block" can cause display problems, and IE doesn't really deal with the "table-row" stuff very well.

Comment: Setting it to block can cause display problem? Are you saying my answer is not correct then? Can you please give some explains of this

Comment: 'block' is not the proper display value for a table row. IE will interpret it the way you want, but Firefox (and others) will not. This is not apparent in the simple single row, single column sample in this question, but it easy demonstrate in a larger table.

Comment: it seems like it should work, but it has bitten me a couple of times